How do I take my App Service offline, test the new app, then go online?
When I go to push my site from staging to production on Azure App Service, I often need to run a SQL script to update the database schema. So is there a way to:

Take the site offline
Run the SQL script
Swap from staging to production
Test the production site
Make the site online

The problems I've hit are:

Swap removes app_offline.htm making the site public
There's no way to test the site if there's an app_offline.htm page.


Check this SCM_CREATE_APP_OFFLINE option once.

After swapping the Production to Staging, create another slot same as staging(test).Perform the testing in that newly created staging test slot , then swap it back with the production slot.

@Harshitha I once had an app that worked fine on staging and crapped out in production. So I’d like to test production before it is set online.


Swap removes app_offline.htm

Yes, the swapping has the option only to stick the Configuration settings.

If you swap the Production slot(which has app_offline.htm), the Production slot lose the html file replacing with the swap slot.

Check the below steps to test the production slot.

Create the app with your requirement and add app_offline.htm to it.


Deployment:


In the newly created App Service, create a dev/staging slot .


This creates a new slot without any code and with same configurations from the deployment slot.

In Visual Studio, remove the app_offline.htm Deploy the same app to newly created dev slot.





Now run the scripts which you have mentioned. Your dev slot is same as your deployment slot (with same configurations).

Test the dev slot,and swap the production with dev now.

When you swap the slots,app_offline.htm will be moved to dev slot.


After swap:
Dev Slot:

Deployment Slot :

